# What causes 'go build' to fail with 'unexpected NUL in input'?

Tags: go

I have a Linux VM where I am trying to compile a simple Go package. The package was retrieved into my user directory with git:

```
$ git clone [...]/test.go
Cloning into 'test.go'...
done.
$ cd test.go/
$ ls
main.go
```

I set up the GOPATH and build:

```
$ export GOPATH=$PWD; echo $GOPATH
/home/vagrant/test.go
$ go build
$ ls
main.go test.go*
```

So far so good. But now when I try to build again, it fails:

```
$ go build
can't load package: package .: read /home/vagrant/test.go/test.go: unexpected NUL in input
```

Deleting the test.go file before building will allow it to build. But this is inconvenient because tools like github.com/codegangsta/gin which try to rebuild the package will fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repository was named `[...]/test.go`, and the default container directory for `git clone` is the repo name, so the containing directory is named `test.go\`.

From `go help build`:

> If the package is main and file names are provided, the file name
>   derives from the first file name mentioned, such as f1 for 'go build
>   f1.go f2.go'; **with no files provided ('go build'), the output file
>   name is the base name of the containing directory.**

In this case the output is a file called `test.go`. The problem is:

> In the directory containing the package, **.go**, .c, .h, and .s **files are considered part of the package**

During a `go build` if the output from a previous build, `test.go`, exists, it will be treated as a source file, triggering the 'unexpected NUL in input' message.

The problem can be resolved by renaming the directory to avoid the build output having a name that will be considered part of the package.